# Actualizar Layout desde thread externo

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, layout

Estoy intentando actualizar una LinearLayout desde una clase fuera de la activity y al hacerlo me da la siguiente: `exception`

> Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException:"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Esto es lo que tengo:

Lo primero que hago es lanzar un hilo que cada pocos segundos comprobará que tengo conexión con el servidor.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    this.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    context = this;

    Task.Run( () => ComprobarConexion());
}
```

Este es el método que utilizo:

```
protected static void ComprobarEstado()
{
    while(true){
        TestearConexion();
        Thread.Sleep(segundos * 1000);
    }
}
```

Y aquí compruebo que la conexión está funcionando:

```
public static void TestearConexion()
{
     try{ 

         WebService.Test();

     }catch(Exception ex){ //En la realidad tengo completadas distintas excepciones.

          LayoutInflater lDesconexion = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
          View vDesconexion = lDesconexion.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_disconected, null, false);
          MainActivity.contenidoPrincipal.RemoveAllViews();
          MainActivity.contenidoPrincipal.AddView(vDesconexion);

     }
}
```

La excepción me salta al tratar de modificar `MainActivity.contenidoPrincipal`.

> ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el fallo de conexión?

Comment: Puedes utilizar [Java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) y llamar al logger en el catch con la conexión

Comment: Probaste usar [Device.BeingInvokeOnMainThread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms)? No he trabajado con xamarin, pero por lo general no se puede modificar el hilo de la vista desde otros hilos de manera directa..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, debes entender como funciona un [Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.8) y un [Thread](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8) para simular una ejecución asíncrona.

### No recomendado: Thread.Sleep

---

> `Thread.Sleep`:  es la forma clásica de suspender la ejecución. Este
>   método *suspenderá el hilo actual hasta que haya transcurrido el
>   tiempo especificado.* Cuando llama a `Thread.Sleep`, no hay nada que
>   pueda hacer para abortar esto, excepto esperar hasta que transcurra el
>   tiempo o al reiniciar la aplicación. Eso es porque `Thread.Sleep`
>   **suspende el hilo que está haciendo la llamada**.

### Recomendado: Task.Delay

---

> Actúa de una manera muy diferente a `Thread.Sleep`. Básicamente,
>   Task.Delay *creará una tarea que se completará después de un retraso
>   de tiempo*. `Task.Delay` no bloquea el subproceso de llamada, por lo
>   que **la interfaz de usuario seguirá respondiendo**.

### Diferencia en memoria entre Thread.Sleep y Task.Delay:

---

> El problema `Thread.Sleep` es, que durante el tiempo que Thread está
>   en reposo, **no se puede usar para otra tarea**. Perder la dosis del
>   hilo no significa necesariamente que estamos perdiendo el tiempo de
>   CPU, pero **hay un costo por crear nuevos hilos** y mantener vivo un
>   hilo no utilizado. Esto no es importante en las aplicaciones de
>   escritorio, porque hay mucha memoria disponible, pero en los
>   servidores o aplicaciones móviles, si, ya que hay que conservar la
>   memoria RAM y eso es muy importante. Así que en lugar de
>   `Thread.Sleep` se recomienda utilizar `Task.Delay`. Al hacer eso
>   cuando esperamos, el hilo se puede utilizar para otras tareas. Lo que
>   significa que mientras esperamos, el hilo se libera de nuevo a su
>   llamador o grupo de hilos y **no se desperdicia ningún recurso en el
>   proceso**.

Entendida la diferencia, aquí vamos con la solución:

### Solución:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    this.RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

    // Crea una variable estatica tipo Activity
    Activity = this;

    ComprobarConexionAsync().GetAwaiter();
}


protected static async Task ComprobarConexionAsync()
{
    int factor = 1; // Factor a multiplicar del tiempo
    int intentos = 0; // Intentos actuales
    int limite = 5; // limites intentos de conexión como máximo

    void MostrarConexionFallida() 
    {
        // No es necesario, porque estas en un Task, pero para salvarte correr en el UI
          MainActivity.Activity?.RunOnUiThread(() => 
          {
                Toast.MakeText(MainActivity.Activity, "No se puede conectar con el servidor", ToastLength.Long).Show();
          });
    }

    // Mientras no se compruebe la conexion
    while(!TestearConexion())
    {
        await Task.Delay(++factor * 1000);
        if(++intentos >= limite){
           MostrarConexionFallida();
           return;
        }
    }

   // En este punto hay conexión
}

public static bool TestearConexion()
{
     bool conectado = true;
     try
     { 
       WebService.Test();

     } 
     catch(Exception ex)
     { 
          conectado = false;
     }

   return conectado;
}
```

**Recomendacion:** si vas a utilizar un metodo para comprobar una conexión de un WebService deberias crear una clase Singleton utilitaria y no adjuntarlo a un Activity. Los Activity tienden a encargarse de muchas tareas y tu codigo se puede ver polucionado con codigo de utilidad.

**Referencias y ejemplos:**

- [Thread Sleep vs Task.Delay](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21177.visual-c-thread-sleep-vs-task-delay.aspx)
- [When you should use Task.Delay](http://hamidmosalla.com/2018/04/05/when-should-you-use-task-delay/)